# Using the same letters of Recommendation from previous admission cycle

Tags: graduate-admissions

My question is geared toward Math PhD programs, but perhaps I will broaden it a bit, so it serve useful for future questions. Hypothetically, if you applied to a graduate program and didn't get in a given admission cycle, is it viewed negatively by the admission committee if you applied to the same institution with the same letter writers next year of the admission cycle.

Comment: You should always try to get newer up to date, letters, if the first set didn't work. From personal experience, if it doesn't work the first time, trying again with the same package typically doesn't provide you a major benefit.

Comment: What if a component in one's application other than the letters was weak and improved upon the next admission cycle, is using the same letter writers viewed negatively by the admission committee?

Comment: @Compass When you mean up to date letters, do you mean different letter writers?

Comment: It can be the same writer, but have them update with what you did in the year or 6 months between. And get a new writer for what you did that extra year.

Comment: @Compass Can you please turn your commends into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to get newer, up-to-date letters, if the first set didn't work.

You should try your best to get a letter specifically from the gap year, such as work experience or another type of academic program, that would benefit you greatly.

From personal experience, if it doesn't work the first time, trying again with the same package typically doesn't provide you a major benefit and ends up being you wasting money for admissions fees.